# Python Character Encoding

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a python script that retrieves information from a web service and then looks up data in a MySQL db.  The data is unicode when I receive it, however I want the SQL statement to use the actual character (Băcioi in the example below).  As you can see, when I try and encode it to utf-8 the result is still not what I'm looking for.

```
>>> x = u'B\u0103cioi'
>>> x
u'B\u0103cioi'
>>> x.encode('utf-8')
'B\xc4\x83cioi'
>>> print x
Băcioi ## << What I want!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your encoding is working fine. Python is simply showing you the `repr()`'d version of it on the command line, which uses `\x` escapes. You can tell because of the fact that it's also displaying the quotes around the string.

`print` does not do any mutation of the string - if it prints out the character you want, that's what is actually in the contents of the string.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL - what do you mean? They're already getting it to print that way, because that's what the string is. No changes are necessary.

Comment: Yep, that was a dumb comment. I'll be over in the corner